# ¿Cual es la verdadera intención con las puntuaciones negativas?

Tags: discusión, votos, comentarios

En muchas ocaciones me he encontrado con publicaciones las cuales si bien pueden tener de alguna manera mal redacción o la mayoría de veces por el desconocimiento al momento de realizarla cometen errores o no son muy claros al momento de generar la pregunta. El echo es que he podido notar que algunos usuarios con mas experiencia se limitan a tratar de *"hundir"* la publicación *"en mi opinion personal"* con comentarios displicentes o votos negativos en algunos casos a usuarios nuevos o con poca experiencia (*como yo*) que si bien no cuentan con mucho recorrido en este tipo de foros, participan con el animo de aportar de alguna manera sus conocimientos y mejorar la comunidad.

A lo que voy es, por que no orientar y tratar de darle un mejor manejo a las publicaciones que no están muy claras o mal redactadas antes de votar de forma negativa, incentivando con esto a que las personas se animen a exponer sus dudas y mejoremos como comunidad, ya que en algunas ocasiones este tipo de acciones hace que muchos usuarios se abstengan de generar una pregunta o se desanimen de una u otra manera.

Comment: @Alan Totalmente de acuerdo que sucede en algunos casos y que no es lo deseable... Me gustaría ver algún ejemplo de lo que mencionás, para poder contextualizarlo correctamente.

Comment: Creo que el moderador debería mostrar un poco de mesura al referirse a los usuarios del sitio. LLamarlos "muchedumbre" o "grupo de autómatas", por ejemplo, o decir que "supuestamente tienen la razon" (si no la tiene la muchedumbre, ¿la tiene el moderador?). Este sitio funciona con méritos. Y si la muchedumbre atómata que supuestamente tiene la razón vota negativo, así funcionan las cosas. O se cambian las reglas o se respetan o el moderador usa sus superpoderes para que solo cuenten los votos que él quiere que cuenten.

Comment: Me anime a tocar el tema por que ya lo había visto anteriormente y no son muchos los casos pero si ocurren, ademas por que tuve un problema en algo que estoy desarrollando y no se como solucionar este de la mejor manera, coloque el caso en cuestión y lo cerraron. Si bien estoy de acuerdo con los motivos del cierre, no encuentro otra forma de expresar el problema ademas de no tener algún tipo de asesoría por parte de las personas que sugirieron el cierre. [post](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21454/7384)

Comment: @Alan Ese no es un caso de votos negativos (tiene +4/-1), sino de cierre de pregunta. Personalmente, lo reabriría, y también creo que se puede mejorar un poco (comentado recién en la pregunta)

Comment: @toledano sí, pero cualquier persona puede ganarse los méritos y luego crear caos. Sobretodo los usuarios que repiten su mismo comportamiento de no explicar nada, solo votar en negativo/a cierre que no apoya a los nuevos usuarios.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No me considero ni un autómata ni parte de una "muchedumbre" la verdad. Intento hacerlo cada vez mejor pero no me sienta muy bien que te refieras a mi de esa manera la verdad. Mi intención siempre es ayudar y mejorar. Del caso concreto del Post, yo mismo hice la revisión y me pareció 100% sobre opiniones, si se cierra por ese motivo pensé que no hacía falta comentario.

Comment: @Mariano Yo no tengo claro que se pueda reabrir en su estado actual la verdad.

Comment: @MiquelColl Entiendo perfectamente tu punto de vista, y la revisión también me parece bien. La pregunta, así como está formulada, se presta a eso... Es solamente que esa pregunta, junto a una buena respuesta de pros y contras de generar un pdf en el server o en el cliente creo que puede ser aceptable... Sin embargo, sin duda es un caso que está en el límite.

Comment: @Mariano Siempre intento mirar si ya existen respuestas (y si son buenas). Vi que no había nada bueno (2 respuestas de muy baja calidad) y que sin una edición de la pregunta era imposible responder. Tienes razón en que *puede* ser respondida pero por eso está `en espera` =P. A ver si Alan lo actualiza y lo podemos ayudar.

Comment: @MiquelColl Lo sé. Siempre reviso las revisiones que fui haciendo y coincido en la gran mayoría con tus revisiones. Es cierto, una edición a la pregunta es lo mejor para este caso.

Comment: Mejor investigo por mi cuenta, la verdad es que me tomaría mucho tiempo arreglar el post y es algo que tengo que entregar pronto de igual manera muchas gracias :)

Comment: @MiquelColl no me refiero a ti. Me refiero a aquellas personas que, hasta el día de hoy, esa sigue siendo su actitud sobre la evaluación de preguntas. Si no eres del grupo de personas que solo abre el navegador, entra al sitio, **vota a cerrar y nunca comenta** entonces ¡Felicidades, no eres un autómata! Eres un ser humano con el que se puede dialogar mediante comentarios, meta, chat, etc. Es más, es un grupo reducido de usuarios que lastimosamente son los autómatas (y que siempre me referiré a ellos así porque siguen con su misma "actitud" [? si así se le puede decir]) y no suman al sitio

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si ese grupo de usuarios es pequeño y está delimitado por qué no quitarles sus privilegios?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza AFAIK votar para cerrar = elegir un motivo.... *entonces ¡Felicidades, no eres un autómata!*. Tu entiendes que es ser un moderador? Como puedes decir que alguien que ha conseguido un privilegio (ganandoselo, no como tu, que fuiste elegido nepoticamente) no puede actuar como le venga en gana si sigue las reglas del foro? al menos haz commo miquel e inicia una discusion y no seas un dictador como hasta ahora. Sinceramente cambia tu actitud o deja de ser moderador

Comment: @MiquelColl quizas porque las reglas del foro son las que son y esta gente, aunque no guste, las está cumpliento a rajatabla? (es mas, con sus votos esta colaborando mas que alguien que ve una pregunta mala y no hace nada por compasion)

Comment: @JordiCastilla Al estar en beta entiendo que podemos hacer nuestras propias normas hasta cierto punto. Yo veo bien obligar a dejar un comentario si no hay ninguno. Estamos en **beta**, *necesitamos* ser un poco más permisivos (IMHO), que eso NO significa evitar cerrar preguntas; me limito a insistir al tema de los comentarios. He abierto un [post en meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/796/7242) al respecto para que todos pongamos nuestra opinión :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla estamos en beta =P http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish (`public beta`)

Comment: @JordiCastilla Salir de beta no es una tarea fácil. Los cinco parámetros que se muestran en Area51 deben estar en verde (o amarillo al menos si no me equivoco) y este sitio tiene un problema: demasiadas preguntas y muy poca gente respondiendo (aunque parece que el nivel está subiendo al 73%, pero ha estado en caída libre). Hay otros sitios dentro de la red de StackExchange que llevan en beta años, que no meses. Hay que tener paciencia y trabajarse el camino fuera de la beta.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Según este [post en el blog de StackOverflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/06/stack-overflow-in-portuguese-now-with-less-beta/), SO em Português tardó algo más de un año y medio en salir de la beta. No es algo que ocurra en 90 días. Aunque no me sorprendería si a nosotros nos lleva un poco menos de tiempo (considerando que hay más hispano-hablantes en el mundo), pero no nos veo fuera de la beta por al menos 4-6 meses más.

Comment: @JordiCastilla *votar para cerrar = elegir un motivo* no, puedo crear un bot para hacerlo (qué maravilla, un autómata :O). Fuera de eso, tu comentario lo leo como si tuvieses algo contra mí, pero bueno es parte del trabajo :).

Comment: lo reitero **estoy muy en contra de ti como moderador**, y repito eres un buen usuario, pero **no sabes moderar**. Ahora borralo si quieres que tengo el markdown

Comment: Yo vote en contra de esta publicación, no con la intención de hundirla, si no por que me opongo a este tipo de discusión. Me parece que se habla desde la calentura y, si la pregunta no surge de mejor parte de la cabeza del OP, para mi, no tiene cabida en este sitio, sobre todo en meta.

Comment: Cierto! lo mas sensato creo yo, es eliminarla, no pensé que seria motivo de discordia creo que no estamos preparados para un debate a cerca de un tema como estos, se perdió toda la intención con la cual fue publicado y genero malos entendidos entre algunos usuario mis sinceras disculpas :(

Comment: @Luiggi Conocés mi punto de vista (ya lo discutimos muchísimas veces).. Quiero agregar algo tratando de ser constructivo. Estoy de acuerdo con gran parte de tus posturas, pero siempre hay 1 punto específico que me impide ponerme de tu lado, **[cuando generalizás](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/1686)**. Más aún si luego tenés que decir: "*no me refiero a ti. Me refiero a aquellas personas...*". Me gustaría que los casos de "*autómatas*" sean marcados mucho más específicos y con un historial bien concreto que lo avale. Y en esos casos, que se actúe con todo el peso y poder de ♦

Comment: @Jordi Totalmente de acuerdo con:"*haz como Miquel e inicia una discusión*". En cuanto a "*puede actuar como le venga en gana si sigue las reglas del foro*" creo que no está del todo bien, ya que las *reglas* aún se están definiendo y son **genéricas** -cada caso concreto debería evaluarse con sentido común, incluso cuando no haya una *regla* que lo obligue. Y creo que es irrelevante que digas "*elegido nepóticamente*" (y desconozco como fue), porque creo que el cómo no influye en absoluto y también soy muy crítico (constructivamente), sin olvidar de dar crédito al trabajo que se realiza.

Comment: @Alvaro "*Los cinco parámetros que se muestran en Area51 deben estar en verde*"... Entiendo que no es así, y cada caso se evalúa por separado, con criterio pero esas variables sirven cómo indicadores no excluyentes (ahora no encuentro el post que lo explica)... "*demasiadas preguntas y muy poca gente respondiendo*" en parte es cierto, pero no por el 73%. Fijate que [SO] **[tiene 72%](http://stackexchange.com/sites)** y [pt.so] 78%

Comment: @Alvaro [pt.so] tardó algo más de un año y medio en graduarse, pero el factor principal es porque se tomó como caso testigo para agregar localización en SE y requirió desarrollo para agregar utf8 y traducciones a lo largo de toda la interfaz (tenemos que agradecerles a ellos :)

Comment: @Luiggi "*puedo crear un bot para hacerlo*" <-- y si se usa, sabrás que es relativamente viable de detectar y hacerlo fallar, para probarlo y sancionarlo

Comment: @Alvaro "*no me sorprendería si a nosotros nos lleva un poco menos de tiempo (considerando que hay más hispano-hablantes en el mundo)*" <-- Es cierto, pero también es cierto que los desarrolladores que hablan español suelen utilizar mucho más el inglés, y los que hablan portugués son más reticentes a ello.

Comment: Darsela en que somos los mejores del planeta que nunca cometemos errores y alejar a los nuevos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo con tu punto de vista y creo que es mejor educar a los usuarios a motivar a los autores de preguntas no muy bien escritas a que expliquen con más detalle o más claridad lo que proponen investigar.

El uso de los comentarios para este tipo de motivación es justificable y apreciada.  La plataforma que tenemos usa de las puntuaciones negativas como la manera en que comunicamos al autor de una pregunta o respuesta que lo aportado no es útil. Tenemos dos maneras de expresar nuestro disgusto (1) comentarios que expliquen como se puede mejorar la pregunta/respuesta (2) votando a contra de la pregunta/respuesta.

Cada uno decide la mejor manera de hacer esto. De nuevo, lo mejor (y lo ideal) seria ayudar con comentarios.

Comment: Yo pienso que debería haber una regla para los usuarios con el poder de votar a cierre que al hacer el enésimo voto a cierre  (3ro, 5to,) sin haber publicado un comentario en la pregunta a votar no se pueda realizar el voto y de esta manera estos usuarios tengan que proveer un comentario o alguna estrategia similar.

Comment: @Luiggi ¿Auditorías ([review audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/304899))?

Comment: @Mariano es una alternativa también.

Answer (score 13):

Se que me la voy a ganar con esta respuesta (y con la [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/800/para-cuando-unas-elecciones-para-tener-un-moderador-moderado-en-vez-de-un-hooli) relacionada), pero la verdad, tal y como se esta poniendo este foro, me la suda.

---

Mi opinion?

**Me parece una pregunta victimista**

100% de acuerdo con Juan, aunque la educacion debe ser en **usar bien el foro**, no en votar negativamente y no comentar, porque eso puede ser un buen uso (no me refiero a votar indiscriminada o mecanicamente!).

Te voy a girar el argumento, yo estoy hartísimo de votar en contra a causa de encontrarme con votos positivos en preguntas **MUY MAL FORMULADAS** ([1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21713/detener-media-player-android-al-recibir-llamadas-o-que-otra-aplicacion-use-el-a), [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21649/manejar-un-type-de-sql-desde-java), [3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21605/android-studio-error-converting-result-java-lang-nullpointerexception-lock-n))

¿Tiene esa gente tiene que dejar un comentario también? O es que como el voto es positivo ya no importa porque no frustra (aunque engaña y desvirtua al foro)?

**¿O es que estás aqui para ganar reputacion y conseguir tus respuestas sin importarte las normas del foro y no para ayudar?**

Un voto (positivo, negativo o de cierre) es una opinion, que no te guste es otra cosa pero asi es como funciona **TODO** StackExchange, y personalmente creo que es muy bueno.

El problema parece ser **la reputacion**, que **es como comida o droga para mucha gente** que incluso es ofensiva contra quienquiera que le vote.

Además, piensa que quizas un usuario que quiere colaborar no tenga tiempo (ni ganas) para escribir 30 comentarios repetitivos al día poniendo lo mismo en cada uno, pero si de votar 30 preguntas, si no te gusta, postea en otro sitio que no tenga este sistema y sin problemas, pero quejarte asi creo que es victimista.

Comment: Calmate, a mi parecer es una respuesta bastante aireada, todos tenemos la oportunidad de opinar a cerca de esta comunidad, tratemos de generar conciencia y educar a las personas para que no solo usen el foro como tu lo dices para *ganar reputación* o cosas similares si no para tener en realidad un sitio donde podamos encontrar las respuestas. Claro el voto negativo es necesario solo que debería ser usado de mejor forma como dice @Juan M

Comment: @alan y no el positivo? Yo tb defiendo el buen uso como yo lo veo. y claro que es una respuesta alterada a causa de tu actitud victimista... Juan es moderador, yo no, por tanto puedo defender vehementemente mi postura igual que tu la tuya

Comment: @alan, y por cierto, si no estas de acuerdo **vota en contra hombre**, que pides coherencia en los votos pero no la das!!

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con esta respuesta (y voté +1). Pero quería aclarar que sólo no estoy de acuerdo con llamarlo victimista. Es más, si esta pregunta generó toda esta discusión (que considero que hace falta en el sitio), es una excelente pregunta por el tipo de respuestas y nuevas preguntas que generó (dicho sea de paso, también estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de JuanM)

Comment: @JordiCastilla estoy de acuerdo con usted, el voto positivo se ignora pero es muy importante no andar votando porque sí y un voto mal dado ya sea positivo o negativo genera la misma basura. En cuanto a la pregunta, yo participé en el cierre sinceramente no tuve tiempo de responderle al usuario además de que ya había gente solicitando que se mejore, sinceramente no entiendo la discusión. A mi entender era una pregunta que así no tenía cabida.

Answer (score 1):

Debo decir que yo he tenido esta experiencia **varias veces** en esSO. De hecho me quejé al principio, al comprobar cómo preguntas que planteaba tenían la guillotina al cuello antes de su media hora de vida, sea por considerarse duplicadas, sea por considerarse demasiado amplias.

También hubo [un caso extremo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1569/29967) de una pregunta contestada por mi en la que cierto usuario no estuvo de acuerdo en que la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54427/29967) fuese aceptada, de modo que creó otra pregunta y marcó la mía como duplicada. En ese caso yo usé un término quizá un poco fuerte y que podría sonar hasta desagradable. Dije que al parecer en ciertas áreas de esSO algunos actuaban como verdaderos *caciques*, en el sentido de que actuaban como si sintiesen que su terreno estaba amenazado cuando algún usuario, sobre todo recién llegado, interviniese respondiendo y dichas respuestas eran aceptadas.

El término *cacique* es fuerte, pero aunque no con la misma intensidad que antes, sigo creyendo que hay ciertos comportamientos caciquiles en esSO. Y también he tenido la impresión de recibir votos en contra por algún motivo personal, no por la naturaleza o calidad de la pregunta. Porque además dichos votos en contra se han producido casi siempre después de un enfrentamiento en el terreno del *cacique*, por seguir usando el término, aunque sea fuerte.

Aquí hay algunos ejemplos de preguntas o respuestas votadas en contra sin explicación:

[Diferencia entre int [] e Integer[]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54427/29967) : Recibió retirada de voto a favor y voto en contra después de un enfrentamiento al estilo mencionado. **EDIT:** Y otro voto negativo conjuntamente con esta respuesta.

[¿Qué es una promesa en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64863/29967) : Recibió un voto en contra. Tiene una recompensa abierta, quizá sea ese el motivo

Hay al menos dos casos de preguntas que fueron cerradas después de haber tenido respuesta. El motivo del cierre es que un OP dedicado a esa área creó dos preguntas-respuestas consideradas a mi juicio *ficticias* tomando como referencia una pregunta real planteada por otra persona.

Para evitar ese tipo de escenarios que en varios casos resultaron ser muy desagradables y además una pérdida de tiempo, he decidido no intervenir en las preguntas en que esa persona ya lo ha hecho a través de una respuesta o incluso de algún comentario.

No digo que todo sea perfecto de mi parte, también yo he cometido errores. Y sobre todo al principio me entraron ganas de abandonar esta comunidad. Pero con el tiempo las cosas han cambiado. Gracias a Dios esos comportamiento son mínimos y he descubierto aquí gente muy sensata y sé que aún aquellos que a mi juicio se han comportado así, lo han hecho o lo hacen con buena intención.

En definitiva, este tipo de situaciones es mínima, es mucho mayor todo el aporte que se hace desde aquí a tanta gente y lo que cada uno aprende en ella.

En cuanto a **votar negativo**, tengo por norma siempre que lo hago dejar un comentario al autor de la pregunta o respuesta, indicando por qué he votado negativo, a no ser que sea evidente que la pregunta está fuera de lugar. A mi juicio, cuando se vota negativo es preciso dar la cara, diciendo por qué se ha votado negativo.