# Haz +1 a las preguntas que respondes

Tags: discusión, preguntas, votos

Me encuentro con preguntas que tienen respuestas, a veces varias respuestas.

Pero tienen 0 votos. 0 positivos y 0 negativos.

¿Por qué tomarse la molestia de responder una pregunta que no se merece tu +1?

Quiero pues invitar a que seamos más espléndidos a la hora de hacer +1 en las preguntas, sobre todo si hemos puesto o votado una respuesta.

Hay casos y casos. Puede que alguien vea una pregunta que cree que necesita una edición de mejora y se está esperando a que suceda para el +1 pero no se espera para responder. Y puede haber otros mil motivos. Aún así echo en falta más votos a las preguntas.

Comment: ¡Al fin alguien más menciona esto! Hay que votar más, ¡¡¡es la mejor forma de lograr compromiso por parte de los usuarios de menor reputación!!!

Comment: Básicamente, [vote early, vote often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

Comment: Vota en las preguntas y también las respuestas. Es increíble la lista de respuestas buenas con baja puntuación o ninguna. En mi opinión responder implica mayor trabajo que preguntar ya que debes escribir para el que pregunta y el que vendrá despues. Muchas veces he visto que comentan "gracias, me sirvió" y ni un voto positivo.

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con vos. Si me tomo el trabajo de responder, entonces es porque la pregunta fue lo suficientemente interesante como para tomarme el trabajo. Si no está bien formulada, no puedo responder..porque no tengo idea de qué quiere el OP. Y si no es interesante, tampoco respondo. Hay varios ejemplos de preguntas que tienen 0 puntos con 5 respuestas con más de 2 o 3 votos ¿Cómo puede ser que la respuesta tenga esa reputación si la pregunta que le oiginó, tiene 0?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No estoy del todo de acuerdo con el titulo aunque creo que si con el fondo. Para mi debería ser algo como:

## Interactua en todas las preguntas [respondas o no].

Voy a explicarme:

Responder a una pregunta no implica que creas que la pregunta esta bien formulada, ni siquiera que sea una buena pregunta, simplemente dice que sabes la respuesta.

Si damos +1 a lo que contestamos estamos contaminando el foro con informacion incorrecta para *motivar* o no *desmoralizar* a los [usuarios a los que les afectan los votos negativos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/788/cual-es-la-verdadera-intenci%C3%B3n-con-las-puntuaciones-negativas), haciendo que, en consecuencia, la calidad del foro pague por ello, teniendo malas preguntas con puntuaciones positivas que en un futuro seran basura digital.

Como ya he comentado en [otras ocasiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/799/517), si que **soy partidario de interactuar siempre en todos los hilos que puedas**.

En el caso de que no creas que hay que dar ni positivo ni negativo, siempre tienes la posibilidad de comentar o marcar la pregunta para revision, para cierre o como duplicado.

Si haces alguna de estas 6 acciones en las 10 o 15 preguntas que puedas visitar cada dia el foro si que va a ganar en calidad, quizas la obtencion de contenido no sera tan rapida, pero IMHO mejor crecer bien que rapido.

Comment: Pues entonces estamos de acuerdo Jordi. Desde luego una actitud de involucrarse a fondo como la que tu defiendes es un grado superior con respecto a lo que expongo en mi pregunta. Mi pregunta trata de animar a involucrarse de una forma concreta en una situación concreta debido a que observo esa situación y creo que es un consejo que puede ser útil. Por supuesto que la involucración no debe quedar en eso ni solo en ese caso. +1 y gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que la calidad es algo por lo que hay que velar y que se ha dejado un poco de lado en aras de lograr mejor masa crítica. Yo particularmente no voto negativo (a menos que hayan escrito algo terrible ;P) porque no le veo la utilidad pero si creo que el sistema de votos debe estar pensado para dirigir a la comunidad a las preguntas y respuestas de calidad. Básicamente así fue como yo aprendí en StackOverflow en inglés y quisiera que funcionara de la misma forma en este sitio.

Comment: _Si damos +1 a lo que contestamos estamos contaminando el foro_ ¿Para qué contestarías una pregunta que contamina SO?

Answer (score 1):

Interesantes puntos de vista.

A mí el `tooltip` del voto positivo me dice algo así como *"la pregunta es clara y bien formulada, el que pregunta ha investigado al respecto (dejando evidencia de ello) y no está encontrando respuesta"* (si es un tooltip muy largo y bastante crítico del accionar del que formula la pregunta en cuestión).

Como me suele suceder cada vez que quiero hacer algo en `git` más allá del `add`, `commit`, `push` o `pull` hoy consulté a *San Google* y chan, [pregunta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-local-branches-no-longer-on-remote) y en una de las respuestas el comando que necesitaba.

Una pregunta que si bien es clara, no demuestra investigación alguna, pero me ha sido muy, muy útil.

Miremos un poco en donde estamos parados acá en SO-es.

La pregunta que veo ahora con más votos es [está](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente). Y le sigue otra sobre [inner y outter joins en SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-inner-y-un-outer-join).

En mi opinión bastante poco interesantes, pueden ser claras en su formulación, pero muestran 0(cero) trabajo de investigación, para mí caen en el tipo de preguntas que estamos discutiendo [acá](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/840/qu%C3%A9-deber%C3%ADamos-hacer-a-las-preguntas-del-tipo-no-he-intentado-pero-quiero-resp). Si bien, a mi entender son temas que todo programador debería al menos conocer (saber que existen como mínimo). Es decir, son conocimiento si se quiere de base.

Pero, no dejan de ser preguntas como la del comando de git ([acá una parienta de esa que está segunda en votos en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git)), que me mi mente no retendrá porque para acordarse está el *Gran Hermano G* y que de acá un tiempo volveré a consultar.

Creo que el sitio le está dando lugar a un montón de gente que se está iniciando en el mundo de la programación o que ya lo hacía, pero se está dando sus primeros pasos en alguna cuestión en particular, por ejemplo programación web y AJAX. Me he cruzado varias preguntas sobre como interactuar entre el navegador (javascript) y el servidor (PHP o Java). Y que le es más fácil consultar en su idioma.

A lo que voy, creo que hoy el voto sirve también para marcar el rumbo de los temas que le interesan a la Comunidad.

Y la verdad que encontrarme [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363/spectrogramarray-a-espectrograma-en-3d-listplot3d) y [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-integrar-esta-validaci%C3%B3n-para-acceder-al-owa-de-office-365-o-portal) como cosas que la Comunidad le interesa saber, a mí personalmente me invita a irme para otros pagos.

**ACLARACION PARRAFO ANTERIOR**

Situación: Quiero participar en la Comunidad respondiendo. Observo las preguntas pendientes con más votos, asumo que son temas que le interesa a la Comunidad y que tendrán mayor impacto, si las respondo. Y me encuentro con esas dos preguntas (que por cierto tienen un tiempito de formuladas).

El resto de la preguntas sin respuestas tiene muchos menos votos. Un pensamiento posible es.. mmmm.. este no es mi lugar, chau, nos vemos.

Es un pensamiento, posible de muchos otros, pero lo tiro sobre la mesa como para pensar. No lo hace más o menos valedero que otro.

Simplemente es para reflexionar sobre este tema en cuestión de los votos.

**FIN ACLARACION**

No estoy diciendo, votemos porque sí. Creo también que hay que interactuar para que las preguntas sean bien formuladas (por ahí todavía no estoy convencido de que venga otro a editarte tu pregunta). Pero también hay que darle un poco de apoyo a la gente que se anima a preguntar (y si yo no pregunto es porque, hago eso de investigar y siempre algo termino encontrando algo que me sirve o son cosas más bien de opinión o de temas muy amplios).

Comment: No entiendo esta parte: "la verdad que encontrarme esto y esto como cosas que la Comunidad le interesa saber, a mí personalmente me invita a irme para otros pagos". Quizás hay personas que sí les gusta, votan a favor y son más de las que te imaginas. Como usuarios, no tenemos ni debemos tener los mismos intereses. Más me parece que te preocupas por preguntas que no te gustan que están con altos votos por sobre preguntas que tú ves más útiles, basado en tu experiencia y en lo que te dedicas o quizás otras razones personales tuyas, pero no significa que ese es el sentir de la comunidad.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza lo aclaro/rectifico en cuanto pueda para que se entienda bien cual era el punto.

Comment: Ahí aclaro a que venía el párrafo en cuestión. Lo dije en ánimo de reflexionar sobre el tema de la pregunta. Espero se entienda.

Comment: @ElAsiduo mira a mi entender las preguntas que mencionas se hicieron por los comitentes de la beta y fue un intento de popular el sitio beta con preguntas, algunas mas interesantes que otras y siempre esto es relativo al ojo que las ve. Yo incluso vote algunas de esas y son temas que no me interesan, podemos habernos equivocado en votarlas pero ten en cuenta que por esas épocas no había mucho por ver. Seguimos en beta y ahora si tenemos muchísimas preguntas y todavía mucho por responder, tal vez será tiempo de ponernos mas críticos? puede ser, en mi opinión si se busca calidad, seguro que sí.