# ¿Se debería de tener algún deber moral cuando alguien hace up vote a una pregunta?

Tags: discusión

Pues eso si alguien hace *up vote* a una pregunta, esta usuario deberia de tener algún deber moral, de estar al tanto de las respuesta para así, de existir alguna que responda la pregunta, este dar el *up vote* a dicha respuesta.

Llevo viendo este comportamiento por mucho tiempo pero hoy he sacado tiempo para realizar la pregunta, existen varios motivo que no entiendo, por ejemplo:

Como alguien da *up vote* a la pregunta y no a la respuesta (claro, si no está atento no la verá), sí sé, que es posible, aunque poco probable que existiendo varias respuestas o una sola, o alguna con el *check* o con algún voto a favor no sea del todo correcta como para que los usuarios que dieron *up vote* no la voten, lo que me lleva a lo siguiente:

Pues si son usuarios que no saben la respuesta y tiene un voto a favor o el *check* es probable que resuelva todo o parte de las dudas, y si es que las respuestas no son buenas al entender del usuario que da *up vote* a la pregunta y no a la respuesta, es que sabe de que va la pregunta, si es asé, crearía una respuesta a la misma. (aunque cabría una posibilidad que todas las respuestas fueran de gente que dio *up vote* a la pregunta, pero creo que no sería el caso más común o quizás sí).

Así que mi duda es la planteada, ¿se debería de tener el deber moral de estar al tanto de las respuesta en las pregunta en las que se hace *up vote*?

Algunos ejemplos sin indagar mucho:

---

- *Up vote* en pregunta 2
- *Up vote* en respuesta/s 0
- *Check* 0
- Respuestas 1

[¿Cómo se puede crear un ejecutable en netbeans para un programa escrito en C?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49725/c%C3%B3mo-se-puede-crear-un-ejecutable-en-netbeans-para-un-programa-escrito-en-c)

---

- *Up vote* en pregunta 3
- *Up vote* en respuesta/s 1
- *Check* 0 (está en *bounty* se entiende que no tenga el *check*)
- Respuestas 2

[Trabajar con dp en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45206/trabajar-con-dp-en-android)

---

- *Up vote* en pregunta 3
- *Up vote* en respuesta/s 0
- *Check* 1
- Respuestas 2

Tiene el *check*, es decir, que satisface al usuario que formula la pregunta.

[Cambiar logotipo al hacer scroll](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49808/cambiar-logotipo-al-hacer-scroll)

---

*Los ejemplos son de hace unos días.*

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, ¿planteas que si alguien hace +1 a una pregunta, debería también hacer +1 a las respuestas que esta reciba? Yo creo que los motivos para votar pregunta y respuesta son bastante distintos, indicados por el tooltip. Para pregunta es _Esta pregunta demuestra trabajo de investigación; es útil y clara_, para respuestas _Esta respuesta es útil (hacer clic de nuevo para deshacer la acción)_. Por tanto, hacer +1 a una pregunta tiene que ver con que se exponga bien y pertenezca al sitio; dar +1 a una respuesta implica más conocimiento y requiere saber si es correcto lo que se dice.

Comment: [hice una pregunta hace tiempo](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/941/falta-de-participaci%C3%B3n) mas o menos sobre esto ... hay gente que viene a publicar sus dudas y ya está (es totalmente valido) pero que cuando encuentran la respuesta valida no la marcan y no dan upvote. lo del upvote es cosa de cada uno pero el sistema del sitio hace que esa aceptacion de respuesta cambia el estado de la pregunta a "con solucion". Puede haber gente tiempo despues que la mire y no sepa si alguna de esas respuestas ha resuelto el problema. :/

Comment: @fedorqui primero gracias por comentar, lo segundo entiendo tu comentario, pero creo que igual no me di a entender lo suficientemente claro creando alguna duda. Cuando dices *¿planteas que si alguien hace +1....* obviamente no me refiero a que si haces mas +1 en la pregunta tengas que hacer +1 en las respuesta, yo me queria centrar a que si se hace +1 en la pregunta se este algo mas atento a las posibles respuestas, el dar +1 o no dependera de muchos factores entre ellos algunos que usted comenta, pero si no miran las respuesta dificilmente podria votar, espero se entienda mejor ahora. Saludos

Answer (score -2):

Lo mejor es votar, cuanto más mejor. Siempre que sea de forma correcta. Vota cada pregunta/respuesta por sus méritos propios. [Vote early/Vote often.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

Si tienes un cierto grado de confianza en que una respuesta es correcta/incorrecta lo mejor es que votes.

Estoy de acuerdo en que si un usuario vota en una pregunta lo mejor sería que votase también en las respuestas si se ve capacitado para ello. No es obligatorio pero sí muy recomendable.

El mismo problema sucede al revés. Preguntas que han recibido respuestas pero que no han recibido votos ni siquiera de quienes pusieron esas respuestas. [Interactua en todas las preguntas [respondas o no].](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/852/301)

Esta es una cuestión importante a resolver antes de salir de beta

Comment: Gacias por comentar. Sobre lo que comenta: *Lo mejor es votar,...* estoy de acuedo. *Si tienes un cierto grado de...* de acuedo. *... en que si un usuario vota..* estoy de acuedo. *...Preguntas con cero votos...* En esta parte no es que, no este de acuerdo sino que yo lo veo de forma diferente, cuando no tienen ningun voto es igual de valida para ser contestada, pues es la base puesto que el usuario que hace la pregunta no puede votarse asi mismo y si la pregunta es buena pues tiene el mismo derecho que otra ha ser respondida, sin en cambio cuando veo por ej.

Comment: un +3 yo interpreto que existe en la comunidad interes en esa pregunta por el motivo que sea, por desconocer la respuesta o cualquier otro, ademas de que no lo percibo de forma lineal sino exponecial, un +3 me indica mucho mas interes que un +2, puede parecer poco logico pero teniendo en cuenta lo a algunos les cuesta dar +1 en comparacion con -1 pues es la sensacion que recivo, que existe mucho interes en la respuesta, y despues veo que no tienen votos las respuesta me desconcierta. Saludos

Comment: Sin embargo con el "vote early/vote often" aparentemente gente votan sin tener sus hechos claros. Tampoco muy sexy.

Comment: Stefan, si votas negativo y pones el motivo y se alcanza un consenso siempre sale alguien ganando. O el que puso la respuesta errónea que mejora su conocimiento o el que puso el comentario y voto erróneo que mejora su conocimiento. A veces ambos. No hay que tener miedo a equivocarse. @AngelAngel He explicado mejor lo de las preguntas con respuestas y 0 puntos.