# Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia

Tags: discusión, faq, votos, convenciones-sociales, artículo

> Esta es una traducción libre de [Vote Early, Vote Often](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/) inicialmente publicada en [Spanish Language](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2639/1674).

¿Te has preguntado alguna vez por qué los botones para votar aparecen tan prominentemente en cada pregunta de [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites)?

[image]

Situar la votación de una forma central es muy intencional; así es como...

- el contenido bueno sube y se consigue destacar
- el contenido malo o incorrecto va para abajo
- los usuarios que consistentemente ofrecen contenido útil acumulan reputación y [se les conceden más privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) en el sitio

Es solamente con el voto que puede emerger un grupo de editores, personas que votan para cerrar preguntas, y moderadores. El liderazgo del sitio se forma a través del voto. Es por eso que las [ligas de reputación](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/381/alltime/es-stackoverflow) muestran un desglose de las franjas de reputación.

[image]

¿Tiene tu sitio un grupo sano de usuarios medios que pueden votar positiva y negativamente, así como editar etiquetas? ¿Tiene también un grupo de usuarios gobernantes con privilegios para editar, cerrar y [moderar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)? Todo esto requiere un nivel suficiente de reputación, que a su vez requiere de usuarios que ejerciten su derecho a voto.

Es por ello que en [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) se muestra una métrica de cuántos usuarios *ávidos* hay, donde *ávidos* se refiere a tener al menos 200 puntos de reputación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(estas son las [estadísticas de Stack Overflow en español](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) al final de la fase Beta, por ejemplo.)

Todos nuestros sitios están pensados para ser un tipo de democracia representativa. Si bien la [elecciones anuales a moderador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election) son una parte importante del sistema, votar preguntas y las respuestas es el mecanismo fundamental a través del cual la comunidad gobierna el sitio en el día a día.

Votar es *tan* importante que nos dimos cuenta de que hay que transmitirlo de forma clara a los nuevos usuarios y así animarlos a que voten. Por ello:

- Al punto que un usuario puede empezar a votar, recibe una [notificación](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/07/membership-has-its-privileges/) en la que se lo explica.
- Existen unas cuantas [medallas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) para hacer más prominente la idea:

  - *Apoyador*, de bronce. Primer voto positivo.
  - *Crítico*, de bronce. Primer voto negativo.
  - *Electorado*, de oro. Votar en 600 preguntas y que al menos un 25% de los votos totales sea a preguntas.
  - *Espíritu deportivo*, de plata. A quien vote positivamente a 100 respuestas "competidoras", esto es, aquellas que existen en preguntas a las que tú también contestaste y tienes una puntuación de al menos 1.
  - *Obligación civil*, de plata. Votar 300 o más veces.
  - *Sufragio*, de bronce. Votar 30 veces en un día.
  - *Vox Populi*, de bronce. Usar el máximo de 40 votos al día.

> En el momento de votar, cada ciudadano debe recordar que no está haciendo un regalo o un cumplido para complacer a alguien -o que al menos no debería hacerlo; sino que está ejecutando una de las más solemnes muestras de confianza en la sociedad.
>   — Samuel Adams

Votar es crucial para nuestra comunidad, tanto como lo es para cualquier democracia. Como moderador, o sencillamente como ciudadano del sitio: por favor, ¡ejercita tu derecho votando pronto y con frecuencia!

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Relacionado: [Haz +1 a las preguntas que respondes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/849/haz-1-a-las-preguntas-que-respondes)

Comment: Esto me suena a [be quick or be dead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTt1vk9nM9c) de Iron Maiden

Comment: Actualmente SOes tiene [uno de los más bajos ratios de votos por cada publicación de toda la red](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2000/127).

Comment: Parece que algunos usuarios han interpretado el eslogan "vota pronto, vota con frecuencia" como un "vota +1 a todo sin importar la calidad" y tampoco es eso. Tener un ratio de votos bajo no es bueno, pero tener una serie de votos malos que van a hacer que contenido de mala calidad aparezca destacado o no se pueda borrar, es peor.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro me extrañaría que una simple publicación en Meta tuviera tanto efecto. Sin embargo, para intentar evitar que provoque ni que sea un voto de más, ¿qué tal si le cambiamos el título? Se me ocurre algo así como: _Si una publicación es buena, ¡vótala positivamente!_. Más directa, ¿qué te parece?

Comment: Deja el título como está. Tienes razón en que el motivo no tiene por qué ser esta publicación, y además es una traducción buena. Como dice @Mariano, necesitamos más votos, y este post puede ayudar con eso.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro vengo observando esas publicaciones que reciben votos ***inexplicables*** antes de tener esta publicación destacada... De hecho, creo que votar temprano y más frecuentemente harían, por ejemplo, que un +3 inexplicable que hoy es "considerable" pase desapercibido. Yo estoy convencido de que uno de los mayores problemas es dónde ponen el mínimo para un +1 [muchos de los principales usuarios de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2000/127) (-que no tiene que ser excelente, para eso están los favoritos/recompensas, sólo útil).