# ¿Cómo se puede considerar una respuesta como correcta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, respuesta-aceptada

Tengo una pregunta acerca de un problema en *Java* y *PHP*. Un usuario me respondió y esa respuesta me sirvió para entender mi problema o solucionar mi problema.

¿Cómo se puede considerar una respuesta como correcta?

Yo opino que existen estos dos tipos de respuesta:

- Buenas respuestas.
- Respuestas que ayudan a solucionar el problema que no están correctamente respondidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muchas de las preguntas de "la vida real" no tienen *una única* respuesta correcta y algunas ni siquiera tienen una. Supongo que por ello el artículo de ayuda [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en lugar de hablar de "respuesta correcta" habla de "**aceptar una respuesta**" y de "**mejor solución**". El artículo sugiere que uno como autor de la pregunta acepte la respuesta que tenga *la mejor solución*.

Cabe mencionar que además de la aceptación de la respuesta están **los votos**, pero a diferencia de la aceptación de la respuesta, para votar se requiere ganar el privilegio de hacerlo, lo cual en realidad es muy sencillo ya que requiere pocos puntos de reputación. Sobre los votos, véase [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65)

Entonces, como autor de pregunta, acepta la respuesta que tenga la mejor solución.

Como miembro de esta comunidad, vota positivo para las publicaciones útiles, claras, interesantes que responden la pregunta; vota negativo las publicaciones que no son claras, no son útiles o que no responden a la pregunta.