# ¿Deberíamos poner un texto más "constructivo" a la hora de enlazar las publicaciones de "¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?"?

Tags: discusión, meta, comentarios

En los comentarios a la pregunta [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/83) ha surgido un interesante debate sobre cómo enfocar el mensaje al usuario.

Mariano expuso inteligentemente que los títulos de cada una de las secciones ([Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/), [Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855) ...) pueden resultar un poco violentas al empezar con un ***te he votado negativamente***.

Si la finalidad de estos comentarios es que el usuario mejore, lo mismo sería más interesante buscar otro redactado genérico para que prime la voluntad de mejorar en lugar de dar importancia al voto negativo que le podemos haber dado.

Por ello, ¿deberíamos cambiar este texto por algún otro?

No pongo respuestas-encuesta para que surja un meta-meta-debate :) ([What should we do with sets of answers that are actually polling options?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279262/209901) y [Are poll-style questions ever acceptable on meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233908/209901))

Comment: Yo estoy a favor de esta propuesta. Estoy abierto a posibilidades, por ejemplo simplemente eliminar la parte de _Te he votado negativamente porque_ y dejar solo las razones. Lo único que no se que título deberíamos ponerle a la pregunta en ese caso...

Comment: @Pikoh se me ocurre algo así como "¿cómo puedo mejorar mi publicación?"

Comment: Pues no veo otra forma de decirlo. La cosa es explicar por qué hemos votado negativo y si obviamos la parte _«te he votado negativamente»_ ¿qué sentido tiene todo eso?

Comment: @blonfu Creo que cualquiera puede agregarle el `"*te he votado negativamente*" en el enlace del comentario, pero lo que me pareció más importante destacar era no hacerlo una regla por omisión.

Comment: Yo creo que precisamente se lanzó esta iniciativa porque votar negativo sin más explicaciones podía no entenderse por algunos usuarios, sobre todo los nuevos. Yo lo veía bien tal y como estaba ya que es de lo que trata: de votos negativos; pero si a la gente le parece mejor otro texto pues se cambia.

Comment: @blonfu yo estoy igual, empecé usándolo como explicador del voto negativo. Después, al ver que la información es muy útil, pasé a usarlo masivamente siempre que veo a alguien nuevo en el sitio cayendo en los errores típicos: imágenes en lugar de texto, no explicar el problema... y en muchos casos votarles negativamente así de buenas me pareció que no era la mejor forma de darles la bienvenida. Por ello, como digo, creo que el cambio en el texto viene porque ha muerto de éxito :)

Answer (score 11):

## Tl;Dr

**Propuesta**

- No indicar `"te he votado negativamente"` como regla por omisión. No tener como predeterminado el voto negativo y ese comentario (es un tema de cuál es nuestra filosofía).
- Que quien quiera agregue ese texto en el comentario luego de votar, pero no inculcarlo para que todos lo usen así.
- Modificar el texto para explicar qué sería mejor o qué acción se espera.

Al final se incluye propuestas de redacción alterna para varios de los textos

## Discusión

¿Se acuerdan cuando entraron por primera vez a SO (o SOes, o el sitio de SE en el que hayan empezado)? ¿Hicieron alguna pregunta? ¿No les fue un poco abrumador estar recibiendo comentarios/respuestas/ediciones de varias personas en pocos segundos mientras que ni siquiera tenían clara la interfaz del sitio y qué se suponía que uno debía hacer?

Bueno, yo tengo eso presente cada vez que veo una pregunta de un usuario nuevo.

En los últimos días vi algunos casos de usuarios nuevos que recibieron comentarios como

> #### Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada.

Y me pongo a pensar que el usuario ni siquiera sabe qué implica un votos negativo... -Ok, sabe lo que es un `-1` y lo ve bien grande a la izquierda, ya de por sí frustrante, pero no sabe qué consecuencias puede tener. ¿Tendrá un ban?  ¿Se le acabarán sus puntos iniciales y tendrá que ver 5 publicidades antes de seguir leyendo el sitio? ¿Tendrá que pagar?

Recordemos que hay cosas que son obvias para nosotros (*cualquiera que esté leyendo en Meta*) pero que no lo son para muchos, y no tienen por qué serlo. La idea de SE es ser un sitio abierto. No cerremos puertas.

Además, no tenemos **ninguna certeza de que no haya intentado nada**. Quizás se estuvo matado durante días intentando solucionar el problema, y simplemente intentó publicar una pregunta lo más acotada posible. ¿No es un poco fuerte decir que no intentó nada sin saberlo realmente? Recordemos que el estilo de muchos sitios es ese: preguntas sin descripción seguidas de un arcoíris de respuestas.

En fin, sí, **me parece violento**. Es un tema de *cuál es nuestra filosofía*. ¿Estamos para asesinar a quien pregunta o para buscar respuestas con la mejor calidad a preguntas de programación? Por más que muchos se merezcan la horca, las preguntas le dan vida al sitio.

Claro que no tengo ningún reparo con quienes ya saben cómo funciona, pero aún así creo que es contraproducente marcar directamente lo malo cuando hay una mejor opción.
<sup><sub>-En los últimos días mis comentarios a lois6b, sstan, Alvaro y gbianchi fueron sin ningún tipo de protocolo, porque así nos manejamos y ellos lo saben.</sub></sup>

Además, un texto sin el "*Te he votado negativamente*" **permite que se usen en más situaciones** (cuando uno no cree que sea para un -1).

**No digo que no se usen para un `-1`**

Hay muchas situaciones que merecen una mano un poco más dura, y en las cuales podemos modificar el texto de estos enlaces hacia un `te he votado negativamente porque...`. Pero me resisto a que sea la moda general avalada en Meta. Prefiero que quede a discreción de quien la use el hecho de que se modifique así.

**Propuesta**

- No indicar `"te he votado negativamente"` como regla por omisión. No tener como predeterminado el voto negativo y ese comentario (es un tema de cuál es nuestra filosofía).
- Que quien quiera agregue ese texto en el comentario luego de votar, pero no inculcarlo para que todos lo usen así.
- Modificar el texto para explicar qué sería mejor o qué acción se espera.

**Posibles textos**

Si bien esto lo estoy redactando ahora, no estoy casado con ninguno de estos textos, y es un poco preliminar, y se puede mejorar, podríamos adaptar cada mensaje a la descripción del problema. Seguramente haya una mejor forma de redactarlo. El punto principal que quería marcar era el de arriba. Esto va a modo de ejemplo:

1. Te he votado negativamente porque no responder a los usuarios que piden clarificaciones no es de ayuda

   - Los consultas que se te hicieron son para buscar la mejor solución a tu problema. [Deberías responderlas para obtener respuestas de calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870).
2. Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda

   - Las capturas, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en dispositivos que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). Por favor, [pega el código como texto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869).
3. Te he votado negativamente porque solo pusiste una imagen de tu excepción

   - Las capturas, no sólo hacen imposible copiar el texto de la excepción para buscarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en dispositivos que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). Por favor, [pega la excepción como texto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873).
4. Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.

   - Un código puede no funcionar por múltiples motivos. En este sitio buscamos respuestas puntuales a preguntas concretas. Por favor [incluye una descripción completa del problema](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871).
5. Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada.

   - Si bien la pregunta podría tener una respuesta, la única forma de responder al problema puntual que estás teniendo es que [detalles exactamente qué intentaste hasta ahora](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874). De esa forma, las respuestas pueden estar acotadas a tu caso en particular.
6. Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte

   - [¿Podrías publicar el código que intentaste hasta ahora?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875) Es mucho más sencillo responder, y encontrarás más chances de que alguien se interese si ya hay una base sobre la cual enfocarse en algo concreto.
7. Te he votado negativamente porque no se aprecia ningún esfuerzo en depurar el código

   - Un detalle de [los pasos realizados para depurar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872) hará que obtengas respuestas más rápidamente y de mejor calidad.
8. Te he votado negativamente porque tu pregunta no incluye los detalles de la excepción.

   - Para encontrar esa solución necesitamos [TODOS los detalles que se pueden encontrar en la excepción](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877), ya que contienen un montón de información que sirve para determinar qué pasa con tu código.
9. Te he votado negativamente porque no has proporcionado un Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable

   - Es mucho más sencillo responder, y encontrarás más chances de que alguien se interese si ya hay una base sobre la cual enfocarse en algo concreto. La idea es que [todas las preguntas tengan un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2876).
10. Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta

    - Este tipo de preguntas puede llevar a diferentes respuestas, por lo que es necesario que [indiques qué investigaste sobre el tema](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878). Es la única forma de contextualizar el problema y no repetir información innecesaria, logrando que obtengas respuestas de mayor calidad.
11. Te he votado negativamente porque un exceso de código no es de ayuda

    - Puede ser difícil encontrar el error entre tantas líneas de código. ¿Podrías aislar tu problema y [publicar exclusivamente el código que sea relevante para tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879)? La idea es que todas las preguntas presenten un [mcve].
12. Te he votado negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente de tu base de datos

    - Las preguntas sobre base de datos requieren mucha información para poder replicar el problema y actuar sobre éste. Para poder encontrar una solución, [es necesario que incluyas más datos en tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880).

Por favor, **editen** cualquiera de estos textos que puedan mejorar sin siquiera consultarme.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en todo. Sobre todo aprecio el recordatorio en cuanto a lo intimidante que puede ser la experiencia para un nuevo usuario. Ciertamente, yo necesitaba ese recordatorio.  Y me da risa lo que dices sobre tus comentarios sin protocolo, porque aún sin protocolo, tus comentarios demuestran más tacto que los míos con protocolo :)

Comment: Yo no tocaría ni una coma de las propuestas que has hecho. Creo que es un tema importante asi que deberíamos dar un tiempo para que más gente se pronuncie,pero por mi parte estoy de acuerdo con aplicar estas modificaciones.

Comment: De hecho,se me ocurre que de todas maneras, en la parte final de la pregunta se pueden poner los dos tipos de enlaces, el _te he votado negativamente_ y el alternativo. De esa manera, será sencillo para cualquiera pegar el que se ajuste mas a su pensamiento

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con los dos comentarios de @Pikoh, así como con lo expuesto en la publicación

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con esto, y paso a explicar porque.. con lo de te he votado negativamente, logramos al tener en una sola linea un link completo que entraran. Con mucho texto, pierden los links (hubo usuarios que me preguntaban que links) y no entran a mirar porque. Mas alla de que no aplico siempre los votos, tener una sola linea clara completa de link ayuda mas que un monton de texto (como teniamos antes).

Comment: Justamente he comentado últimamente en el chat que no estoy de acuerdo con el "te he votado negativamente ....", pero claro, tú lo expones con mucha más claridad ;). En fin, creo que si se quiere seguir con estos links, definitivamente estas opciones son muy superiores a las que se están usando actualmente

Comment: @gbianchi lo de una sola línea es un buen punto.. Y, como digo, el texto es un ejemplo posible, no necesariamente tiene que ser eso. El punto principal está al principio... Se puede ver si se lleva a una línea, u otra opción es poner la descripción sin links, y al final. `Esto es lo que se debe mejorar: <link>` con la URL explícita.

Comment: @gbianchi: Aunque a mi personalmente me gusta lo de la línea entera como link, yo he notado lo opuesto. Como no hay contraste dentro de la línea, algunos usuarios ni se dan cuenta que el texto es un link, y no le hacen click.

Comment: Mucho texto tambien hace que se pierda el link. apenas se notan en mi navegador por ejemplo... hay que hacerlo resaltar de alguna forma. en un monton de texto tambien se pierde...

Comment: @gbianchi Otra opción: `mirá este artículo: <link>`

Comment: ok. eso me gusta mas...

Comment: @sstan es un buen punto este que comentas. También es verdad que el texto largo típico en plan _bienvenido a SOes, lee el Tour bla bla_ desconozco si provoca demasiados clicks en los enlaces que contiene, supongo que porque es un texto demasiado largo y algo burocrático.

Comment: Pues no sé cómo deberíamos cerrar o encauzar la discusión, @Pikoh. A mí me parece que los votos en esta respuesta la convierten en la preferida, si bien podría recogerse lo dicho en los comentarios y crear una... _solución final_.

Comment: @fedorqui Yo tampoco lo tengo claro. Obviamente esta es la respuesta mas votada, pero las otras propuestas tambien pueden ser tomadas en cuenta. Obviamente dejar contento a todo el mundo es imposible, pero a ver se se nos ocurre algo que tenga un consenso lo mas amplio posible...

Comment: @Pikoh claramente, es el momento de crear otra pregunta en Meta para consultar qué tenemos que hacer con esta :P

Comment: @Pikoh bromas aparte, yo lo que sugiero es incluir el texto de esta respuesta de Mariano y añadir dos posibles enlaces bajo cada respuesta: el duro de "te ha votado negativo porque bla" y el más suave.

Comment: @fedorqui yo estoy totalmente de acuerdo. Así cada uno podrá poner el texto que más le convenga.

Comment: @Pikoh ¿hubo algo más de debate sobre todo esto? Digo para continuar con las actualizaciones de las respuestas en [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/83).

Comment: @fedorqui no,nadie se pronunció a favor ni en contra. Así que yo haría caso a esta votacion y seguiría actualizando.

Answer (score 6):

Yo haria otra cosa.. no sacaria lo de te he votado negativamente. Pero lo cambiaria por algo asi como:

> Si recibiste un voto negativo, puede que se deba a.....

De esa forma, cubrimos a los nuevos que no reciben votos negativos, pero tambien cubrimos a los viejos que cometen errores de novatos por apurados.

Creo que de esta forma podriamos dejar en claro que los votos existen.. pero no necesariamente decir que lo votamos...

Comment: Me gusta esa fórmula, voto por eso.

Answer (score 2):

Pues yo no lo veo.

Esta iniciativa trata precisamente de votos negativos, para hacer entender a los usuarios que los votos negativos tienen su utilidad, que no hay que tomárselos como un ataque personal y que no nos debería dar miedo usarlos. Los diferentes enlaces que se han creado explican con detalle las principales razones del voto negativo y cual podría ser la siguiente acción para que esos votos se reviertan.

Me parece bien intentar ser constructivo y de hecho creo que esto lo es, por eso se planteó y algunos trabajaron mucho creando las respuestas cuando podríamos votar sin más contemplaciones y en algún caso dejar un escueto comentario explicando nuestro voto.

Esta plataforma se basa en la reputación y esta depende directamente de los votos, creo que hay que darles importancia y explicar bien como funcionan y querer suavizar las frases eliminando la referencia al voto –mas aún es este tema que es justamente lo que estamos hablando– no me convence.

Comment: La iniciativa si empezó como una manera de explicar de una mejor forma un voto negativo, basado en una propuesta similar en el sitio en inglés, y a mi me parecía injusto que a un usario nuevo se le votara masivamente con negativos sin explicación. Sin embargo, como bien dice @fedorqui _murió de éxito_ y está siendo muy utilizado, hasta el punto de verlo en numerosos posts en los que se aprecia que no se ha votado negativamente. Por eso parece mas sensato y adecuado al uso modificar el texto original, y cada uno es muy libre de añadir por delante "Te he votado negativamente porque..." si quiere

Comment: Por otro lado, una discusión similar a esta se produjo hace mucho años en el sitio en inglés  y se llegó a la conclusión de que explicar los votos muchas veces es contraproducente (de hecho, no se permite comenzar un comentario con +-1 por esa razón). [Aqui hay una respuesta sobre el particular](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777)

Comment: Si se quieren usar los enlaces como un FAQ o una extensión de la ayuda por mi vale, pero sigo pensando que tenemos mucho que mejorar en el tema de los votos, votamos poco y parece que da miedo votar negativo o hablar de ello por no ofender a nadie. Creía que esta iniciativa podría dar un empujón a ese tema.

Comment: Yo no estoy de acuerdo. Si lo estoy en que, y lo pongo en negrita, **hay que votar mucho mas**, pero esta iniciativa no se hizo para aumentar el número y calidad de los votos, sino mas bien para tratar de explicar a los nuevos usuarios que hicieron mal. En cuanto a la explicación de los votos negativos, es algo muy personal. Yo si suelo hacerlo, pero solo si considero que es util. Si preveo que una explicación no servirá de nada mas que como fuente de una discusión, no lo hago.

Comment: Ya sé que no se hizo para eso, tampoco para usar las explicaciones pero sin votar (creo yo) pero eso no quita que pudiera servir para eliminar un poco esa resistencia que parece que hay a votar, en este caso votos negativos pero por algo se empieza.

Comment: Probablemente [lo comentado por @Pikoh](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2938/deber%C3%ADamos-poner-un-texto-m%C3%A1s-constructivo-a-la-hora-de-enlazar-las-publicaci#comment10069_2940) de tener disponibles ambos textos sería la mejor forma de resolverlo. Coincido en que se vota poco, poquísimo, pero creo que esto se debería abordar desde otro ámbito, como por ejemplo poniendo en [meta-tag:destacado] publicaciones del tipo [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/83).