# ¿Donde encuentro información sobre evitar usar imágenes en preguntas?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Revisando algunas preguntas de la comunidad de Unix & Linux, he visto que cuando nuevos usuarios agregan un pantallazo en vez del código relevante, suelen referenciarlos a [este meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Personalmente lo encontré bastante completo sobre los por qué de agregar código y sería bastante bueno tener algo similar en SOes (¿quizás la misma pregunta, pero traducida?) en vez de tener que repetir como loro en los comentarios del por qué no agregar sus benditas imágenes.
Ideal si fuese algún meta tag, al estilo de `[ask]` o `[mcve]`, que pudiese ser agregado a los comentarios.

Comment: no voy a cerrarla por mi mismo.. pero creo que buscabas esto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324 que es la traduccion (con el permiso correspondiente) de lo que enlazaste

Comment: @gbianchi genial. No tuve suerte buscando antes. así que agregadas a favoritos. Gracias

Comment: me parece excelente idea, bueno  tengo una opinion sobre esta parte >he visto que cuando nuevos usuarios agregan un pantallazo en vez del código relevante, suelen referenciarlos a este meta. Personalmente lo encontré bastante completo sobre los por qué de agregar código  yo supongo que no solo en stackoverflow sucede eso , yo cuando estoy en facebook en grupos de software developer siempre recomendamos codigo y no screenshot porque es mas facil testear su codigo , bueno yo siempre he pesando en una tool para evitar que los usuarios publiquen eso  pero nadie se anima, saludos :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay en meta algunas publicaciones sobre el tema. Hace tiempo compilamos varios errores a la hora de preguntar y responder en [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/15301)

Dentro de esa publicación puedes ver los siguientes apartados:

- [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/15301)
- [Te he votado negativamente porque solo pusiste una imagen de tu excepción](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/15301)

Si no te parecen suficientes, o piensas que puedes ampliar la información contenida ahi te animo a editar/agregar lo que consideres necesario.

Comment: Olvidé comentar tiempo atrás, pero me parece un poco hostil lo de "te he votado negativamente porque...", sobretodo para recién llegados a la página, al menos evito darles un -1 y en vez de eso explicarles el por qué de su error. De todas formas, está buena la info para linkearla en comentarios, algún día que llegue un tag para linkear eso será la panacea :) . Saludos

Comment: @AlterLagos si, [ya se comentó que era un poco hostil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2938/15301). Es una traducción directa de un proyecto en ingles que se llama [I downvoted because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/), pero efectivamente podríamos retomar la sugerencia de fedorqui y modificar el texto para suavizarlo.