# Propuesta para solicitar una respuesta como aceptada

Tags: discusión, moderación, interfaz-de-usuario, respuesta-aceptada, propuesta

Muchas veces, usuarios nuevos se registran en stackoverflow para preguntar una duda sobre su código y ya no se les vuelve a ver. Desaparecen, dejando así posts respondidos **sin marcar las respuestas como aceptadas**. Si buscas la etiqueta [javascript] y nos vamos a hace 10 días (tiempo suficiente para entrar y mirar si te han respondido a la pregunta) de 5 publicaciones respondidas solo 1 esta marcada como correcta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto implica que los que se han currado el código no reciban la **reputación** que se merecen y que se **acumulen posts** y posts respondidos dentro del filtro "Sin responder". Por lo que, si te aburres y quieres buscar alguna publicación que todavía no ha sido respondida para pasar el tiempo, vas a tener que entrar en 5 publicaciones diferentes para encontrar una que no esté bien respondida y poder mejorar la respuesta o dar otra diferente. Además, consiguen más visitas sin mérito.

Propongo que la persona que haya respondido tenga un **botón para preguntar** si ha respondido a lo que se pide y **solicitar en tal caso que se le acepte la respuesta**.

Si el que ha preguntado no responde para dentro de 2 días, se podría hacer una **nueva sección** con las publicaciones que están pendientes de ser aceptadas que **solo accederían los miembros con más una cantidad de reputación** y se podrían establecer ~11 votos para determinar si la respuesta se merece ser aceptada o no.

No sé si es posible hacer eso pero yo lo propongo porque me parece buena idea.

¿Qué opináis?

-------------------------------------- EDITADO --------------------------------

Me ha gustado la idea de @Yussef que consiste en cambiar el color de las publicaciones dependiendo del número de votos que contenga la respuesta con más votos. He hecho una edición en Paint para ver como se vería y he establecido el amarillo para las respuestas no aceptadas con más de 2 votos, el rojo para respuestas con votos negativos y las respuestas sin aceptar entre 0 y 2 votos y las aceptadas se quedarían como están.

Aparte también he añadido en cada una de ellas la cantidad de votos que tiene la respuesta con más votos en pequeño.

Si queréis podría hacerlo con otros colores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque parezca que la pantalla de inicio estaría demasiado colorida, en verdad, son pocas las publicaciones que tienen respuestas con votos negativos o con más de 2 votos a favor, así que, desde mi punto de vista, se vería mucho más bonito y visual.

Comment: Interesante... ten en cuenta que: algo asi implicaria un cambio en la red (para todos los sitios), y alguien dentro de la compañia, deberia programar esto. a su vez, habria que proponerlo en meta.. aunque preguntar primero aca es el camino correcto. Luego, tienes un problema mas grave. la respuesta aceptada, es la que soluciona el problema. como se podria demostrar que la respuesta fehacientemente soluciona el problema planteado? no necesariamente reputacion implica conocimiento del tema propuesto...

Comment: otros dos temas.. los que contestaron, si reciben reputacion, de los votos positivos.. no solamente de la aceptacion. Ten en cuenta que tambien, es importante que se planteen bien los tiempos... hay respuestas que lleva tiempo probar y aceptar... y ademas, quien va a aceptar la respuesta? porque hasta este momento, el unico que puede hacerlo es quien pregunta. Que pasa si unos dias despues aparece una respuesta superadora? quien va a cambiar la respuesta aceptada?

Comment: @gbianchi no lo estaba proponiendo tanto por la reputación sino por el tema de la limpieza y de que no haya preguntas resueltas sin aceptar. De todas formas, tienes razón; no creo que merezca la pena romperse tanto la cabeza para ese detalle

Comment: Yo me conformaría con que si una pregunta tuviera una respuesta con "suficientes" votos positivos, adquiera una marca visual (así como las respuestas aceptadas tienen un gran cuadro verde), de esta manera no pierdo el tiempo buscando una pregunta para responder

Comment: Aceptar una respuesta como válida queda a criterio de quien preguntó. No es ni puede ser "obligatorio" que todas las preguntas del sitio tengan una respuesta aceptada. Por ello yo no estoy de acuerdo con tu propuesta. Lo de _"los que se lo han currado merecen la reputación"_ me suena a más de lo mismo sobre lo que yo llamo obsesión por los puntos. Está bien ganar puntos si mi contribución es buena. Deseo ganarlos. Pero no debería ser mi único fin o meta. Ya iré subiendo y me sentiré satisfecho, pero no debe obsesionarme.

Comment: Tengo una respuesta NO aceptada con miles de visitas a la pregunta y muchos votos positivos. La pregunta fue formulada por un usuario respetable y conocido de la comunidad. Jamás he pedido a este usuario que "acepte" mi respuesta como válida. Es su criterio y la verdad es que no me quita el sueño ver una publicación con tantas visitas y que ninguna de las respuestas hayan sido aceptadas. Ahora, si este activo usuario no da como válida una respuesta a su pregunta ¿Porqué otros lo harían por él? ¿Mantendría el AP potestad para desmarcar una respuesta validada por otros? ¿Guerra de validaciones?

Comment: @Yussef no estoy muy seguro, pero me parece que el sitio promueve en orden descendente por cantidad de votos la lista de respuestas. Si una pregunta tiene más de una respuesta, y una de las respuestas tiene más votos que la respuesta válida, entonces será puesta de primero, por encima de la respuesta aceptada. Esto ya es suficiente como efecto visual. Entiendo tu punto, pero creo que el sistema se ajustó de esa forma precisamente para promover las respuestas con más puntaje sobre las otras, incluso si ha sido marcada como válida.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Pero para eso debes entrar a la pregunta, yo digo que sería cómodo tener un indicador antes (ver la foto de esta pregunta), porque en el listado de preguntas te indica si tiene respuesta, cuantas tiene y si hay alguna aceptada, más no la cantidad de votos por respuesta (o en último caso la de mayor). Pero repito, lo veo solo por comodidad no algo fundamentalmente necesario

Comment: En cuanto a tu edición: eso deberías proponer más bien en el Meta general. Y aún así, dudo mucho que sea aprobada, porque la interfaz es bastante confusa (mucho más que la actual, porque la anterior sí era más intuitiva (por algo [el cambio tuvo tantos votos en contra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081))).

Answer (score 10):

Si, eso de "tomar el código entre las garras", me parece muy desconsiderado.

Me gusta tu propuesta, pero termina por proporcionar funcionalidad extra que queda de más:

- No cualquiera puede revisar si una respuesta debe ser aceptada. Si no que debe saber del lenguaje de programación usado. Eso nos indica que una cola de revisión no es la mejor idea y que alcanza con hacerse un filtro personalizado.
- Como dijo gbianchi, el sistema de votos positivos otorga reputación al que contesta, especificamente 10 de reputación por voto, tan solo 5 menos que una respuesta aceptada. Eso significa que casi podríamos "emular" el efecto de una respuesta aceptada usando nuestro voto positivo. Además, el sistema de votos indica la calidad de una respuesta.

---

Por lo tanto, tengo una contrapropuesta para todos los que les preocupe este problema: podés hacerte un filtro. En la sección `Filtrar por` seleccionas unicamente `Sin respuesta aceptada` y luego vas agregando en `Etiquetadas con` las etiquetas que quieras revisar.

Luego, revisa cada pregunta filtrando (con la vista o quizá usando sql (que creo permite el sitio)) preguntas en las que haya pasado mucho tiempo de que la respuesta no fue aceptada y, si te parece que la respuesta debe ser aceptada, dale un +1

Comment: Esto precisamente forma parte de la moderación del sitio que tal vez nos falta alcanzar, me incluyo. Si esto se hiciera con mayor frecuencia, tendríamos un sitio con una calidad superior. Me uno a tu contra propuesta.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Es exactamente el espíritu de la moderación en el sitio. Es muy importante votar, tanto positiva como negativamente, pero en especial de forma positiva (por eso un voto positivo suma mas de lo que resta uno negativo), y los votos pueden compensar e incluso superar la importancia de la aceptación de una respuesta. Recomiendo [esta publicacion](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/15301) y [esta de gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4188/15301) sobre el tema del voto.

Comment: Y ya que estamos, no me resisto a añadir [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/15301) con los motivos por los que una publicación puede haber recibido un voto negativo

Comment: creo que la propuesta encaja similar a una cola de cierre ... algo como debe ser esta una respuesta correcta????

Comment: y pondria como requisito tener mas de  votos positivos en reputacion y la respuesta tener mas de 10 dias de haberce publicado

Comment: Gracias gente :D. @FranciscoNuñezIALover no entendí tus comentarios...

Comment: lo conversamos en el chat no quiero saturar tu respuesta. saludos

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Dale! Mencioname donde quieras que hablemos