# La actitud indignante de algún usuario de Stackoverflow en español

Tags: discusión

Mi intención en esta comunidad es ayudar, aportar y también recibir respuestas cuando plantee preguntas.

No entré a esta comunidad para pasar malos ratos con actitudes que considero **intolerables**.

Hace tres días alguien hizo una pregunta sobre la diferencia entre int e Integer en Java, yo respondí y la respuesta fue marcada por el OP como solución.

**Tres días después,** hoy, apareció en esSO una pregunta parecida a la que yo había contestado y con una respuesta parecida a la mía. Yo marqué la pregunta como duplicada y advertí al autor de que incluso en la respuesta estaba **copiando** parte de mi respuesta a la otra pregunta. Encima, era una pregunta formulada por el autor y respondida por él mismo.

Y lo más indignante, la pregunta original, la que tiene mi respuesta válida **¡ha sido marcada como duplicada!** diciendo que tiene una respuesta válida en la pregunta falsificada, aparecida tres días después en esSO. **¿Cómo puede una pregunta del día 10 de marzo ser duplicada de una pregunta-respuesta aparecida el día 13?** ¿Quienes la marcaron como duplicado se fijaron en la diferencia de fechas antes de marcarla? ¿Se fijaron en la calidad de las respuestas de cada una?

¿Intento de abuso de autoridad? ¿Intento de abuso de poder? No lo sé. Pero si se siguen dando situaciones como estas no tendré otro camino que abandonar esSO.

Esto es injusto e indignante.

- [Esta es la pregunta que contesté yo, **formulada el 10 de marzo de
  2017**.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54419/diferencia-entre-int-e-integer/54427#54427)
- [Esta es la pregunta-respuesta copiada de la anterior, **formulada el
  13 de marzo de 2017**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54916/diferencias-y-limitaciones-entre-int-e-integer)

Comment: Pareciera que lo sucedido nació de ciertas frustraciones expresadas aquí: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1560/criterios-muy-dispares-en-votaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas. No he tenido tiempo de examinar todo en detalle, así que no puedo juzgar, aunque me cuesta entender como la primera pregunta pueda ser marcada como duplicada de la segunda. Lo que sí deseo enfatizar es que espero sinceramente que esta experiencia no cause que abandones SOes. No siempre estaremos de acuerdo en todo, pero no tengo ninguna duda que tu participación enriquece este sitio y sospecho que la mayoría concuerdan.

Comment: Como buen cristiano deberías de tomarte estás cosas con más calma y menos a lo personal, que es tu problema. Las discusiones que tienes con @LuiggiMendoza (que yo también las he tenido) no van contra ti, todo lo que te decía tenía sentido y tu respondías en el ámbito personal. Yo tampoco tengo nada personal contigo, te he ayudado como se puede ver [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53881/19623), donde modificaste una respuesta después de que hubiera otra mejor desde mi punto de vista y donde el punto fuerte que esgrimes estaba ya en la otra. Eso si es un ejemplo de copiar de una respuesta.

Comment: El caso mío en la pregunta "duplicada", sólo puedes decir que haya copiado que `int` no es lo mismo que `Integer` y que uno puede ser `null` y el otro no. Creo que eso es básico, no puedes decir que es una copia, más cuando @sstan había ya dado respuesta en el comentario a la pregunta. Sin embargo tu respondiste a otra pregunta distinta porque lo que dice el OP (que diferencia hay entre la declaración de dos arreglos que parecen contener lo mismo) para ti no es importante, lo importante es el tipo, no que sean arreglos. Esa pregunta tal cual está todavía debería ser cerrada según las normas SO

Comment: Como la pregunta debería ser cerrada (IMO) y la respuesta aceptada no la contesta, en vez de editar la pregunta para que claramente coincidiera con mi respuesta y las demás parecieran hablar de otra cosa (tontería), y por que el tema me pareció interesante pese a la falta de esfuerzo de la pregunta, decidí hacer otra claramente orientada, respondiéndola yo mismo, y como según mi opinión tienen la misma respuesta, la marco como duplicada y la comunidad decidirá. La fecha de creación no es vinculante como puedes leer en meta SOen, sólo si tienen una misma respuesta y elegir la que mejor responde

Comment: Me parece que esta pregunta es demasiado amplia ya que abarca dos temas que tienen en común un par de preguntas. 1. La labor de revisión de los reportes de pregunta duplicada y 2. La originalidad y calidad de las respuestas. Tal vez convenga dejar este hilo para discutir acerca del contexto general y tener adicionalmente espacios separados de discusión de cada uno de los temas, considerando para ello el uso del chat y así como intervención de algún usuario que funja como moderador, no en el sentido de sancionar sino de apoyar mediando entre las partes involucradas.

Comment: @A.Cedano estuve ajeno a la discusión original. Pienso que independiente de la situación, es verdad que debes evitar aludir a ataques personales, algo que parece que no puedes dejar de hacer por algún motivo. Explicando con claridad tus problemas es suficiente, no ha necesidad de insultar libremente a otro. También debes recordar que si la pregunta fue cerrada (con lo que no estoy de acuerdo), no fue sólo **un** usuario el que la cerró

Comment: @Lamak en este caso el que se siente atacado soy yo. No considero normal que al menos dos usuarios de esSO estén casi como al acecho de mis respuestas. Y mucho más si uno de ellos copió una pregunta respondida por mí y encima señaló la pregunta original como duplicada. Si esto no es un ataque y una actitud vergonzosa entonces que es. Creo que las cosas deben decirse con respeto pero con claridad.

Comment: @A.Cedano de acuerdo que deben decirse con respeto y claridad, pero la verdad discrepo que ciertos comentarios tuyos sean de esa forma. Insisto que el tema de la pregunta duplicada no es algo que sea hecho por un sólo usuario, pero bueno, si prefieres sentirte atacado, entonces no puedo hacer nada al respecto

Comment: @Lamak No sé si has leído esto: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1560/criterios-muy-dispares-en-votación-de-respuestas . Y pues sí, me siento atacado y por eso plantée la cuestión aquí. Es más tengo la impresión que algunos se comportan como caciques. ¿Hay caciques en esSO? He chocado con al menos dos caciques de Java en esSO a los cuales al parecer les molestan mis respuestas y que éstas sean marcadas como aceptadas. Es tal la reacción que duplican preguntas autocontestadas tomando datos de mi respuesta y marcan a la pregunta original para cierre. ¿Acaso eso es normal?

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí lo leí, y voté acordé a lo que pienso que es correcto en este caso. Pero lo único que digo es que independiente de esta situación, te insto a evitar usar ataques personales. Entiendo perfectamente la frustración que surge por este tipo de situaciones y otras que se dan en el sitio. Yo mismo estuve desconectado de SOes durante un tiempo por frustraciones al respecto, pero la verdad es que usuarios que dan buenas respuestas y aportes son los que impulsan este sitio como comunidad. Te relaciono como uno de estos usuarios, si me diera lo mismo, no te dejaría comentarios al respecto

Comment: @Lamak Agradezco tu sugerencia y lo tomaré en cuenta para la próxima vez. Saludos.

Comment: Dejando de lado la pregunta en sí (no tengo suficiente conocimiento de Java para hablar), quiero destacar que un duplicado puede serlo de una pregunta más nueva: la idea es seleccionar el mejor ejemplar de un problema y que el resto apunten allí. Como dijo el CM de [se] en [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/209901), _If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one_.

Comment: @fedorqui En este caso la pregunta nueva era duplicada y la auto-respuesta era una copia de la respuesta aceptada como válida en la pregunta más vieja... De todos modos, en este caso, si la pregunta está mal planteada, ¿por qué no sugerir al que pregunta a que la modifique y responder en la pregunta original?

Comment: @A.Cedano _si la pregunta está mal planteada, ¿por qué no sugerir al que pregunta a que la modifique y responder en la pregunta original?_: te doy la razón en esto. Pero nótese que quería dejar claro ese punto: que una pregunta sea más vieja no la invalida para ser marcada como duplicada de una más nueva.

Comment: @A.Cedano si quieres hablarme escribe bien mi nombre para que pueda defenderme. Me encuentro con _"Compórtate como una persona adulta y aporta algo con fundamento"_, _"una actitud tan absurda responde a un sentimiento de frustración"_, _"dos usuarios de esSO estén casi como al acecho"_, _"una actitud vergonzosa"_, _"al menos dos caciques de Java en esSO "_, todo eso sobre mí e imagino sobre quién más. ¿Te parece normal decir eso a alguien sólo porque no te da la razón durante 2 días? Piénsalo. Por otra parte ¿Podrías decirme de una vez qué he copiado de tu respuesta?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque se van a agarrar a las piñas.

Comment: Centrándonos en el hecho puntual de las preguntas duplicadas, yo diría que expongas por qué dices que son duplicadas y que la comunidad decida eso. Considera que 5 personas votaron a cierre y otras 5 a reapertura. Que haya sido re abierta no significa que así deba quedar. Es la comunidad quien decide eso.

Comment: Sostengo que hay dos usuarios de esSO que se comportan como caciques en el área de Java. Lo que narro aquí lo confirma. Haré una cosa: cuando pueda aportar algo lo aportaré, tratando de que sea algo de calidad. Si alguien quiere copiar eso, denunciarlo como duplicado, re-preguntarlo y auto-contestarlo... está en su derecho. Lo que tiene calidad lo tiene y eso se aprecia a leguas. Y lo que es copia mal hecha o bien hecha (es siempre copia), también se nota. Saludos.

Comment: El nivel de gravedad de un problema que es para todos diferente se mide en base al orgullo de cada uno. La humildad te libera de todo y es un buen camino a seguir para ser feliz. No hay que darle tantas vueltas al tema. ¡Paz y bien para todos!

Comment: El mayor problema en cuanto a malas formas es el no indicar a quien ha hecho una pregunta qué ha hecho mal (amplia, no estar clara, etc) y marcar directamente la pregunta para cierre.

Comment: +1 a @MarcLemien Creo que si encuentras un problema de este tipo, es mejor contactar a un moderador e informar antes de hacer un escándalo. No vale la pena hacer un lío porque algunas personas actuaron irresponsablemente. Es mejor tener cabeza fría, conversar con las personas por el chat para informarles tu posición y resolver así el problema.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Esta es la primera pregunta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta la segunda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al parecer el motivo para hacer la segunda pregunta es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tiene razón Awes0meM4n en que la primera pregunta no tiene muestra esfuerzo de investigación. También tiene razón en que el título de la primera pregunta no concuerda con el cuerpo.
Pero un error no se soluciona con otro error. Dos torcidos no hacen un acierto. La solución era editar la pregunta original para mejorarla y no hacer una nueva pregunta que es a todas luces un duplicado.
Y, desde luego, la idea de marcar una pregunta vieja como duplicada de una nueva es absurda.

Toda la discusión sobre si la respuesta de ACedano es correcta o no es irrelevante en lo que respecta a la duplicidad de una pregunta. Una pregunta es duplicada o no en función solo de la pregunta, las respuestas no pintan nada en esa discusión. Aunque, como bien dice Rubén, hay ciertas restricciones operativas a la hora de cerrar por duplicado una pregunta. No se puede cerrar así si no tiene respuestas. Lamentablemente esos criterios operativos no están explicados en [la página de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Si alguien no está de acuerdo con una respuesta puede votarla negativo, puede poner un comentario y/o puede poner otra respuesta. Lo que no debe hacer es poner una pregunta duplicada con su propia respuesta. ¿Por qué se hace? ¿Quizás para no tener que competir con una respuesta que ya tiene muchos votos? Estas actitudes tendrían que cortarse de raíz.

Comment: En cuanto a que las respuestas no pintan para nada, no es del todo preciso, ya que no es posible marcar una pregunta como duplicada de otra que no tenga una respuesta con votos positivos y/o aceptada.

Comment: Tienes razón desde un punto de vista operativo @Rubén. En cuanto a los criterios a seguir para marcar como duplicado yo pienso que solo la pregunta importa, pero esto es opinable.

Comment: +1 _La solución era editar la pregunta original para mejorarla y no hacer una nueva pregunta que es a todas luces un duplicado._ Eso era lo que me decía mi razón, no porque la respuesta aceptada sea la mía, sino porque es algo lógico. El que SO permita que una pregunta antigua pueda ser considerada duplicada de una más nueva no es solamente ilógico, sino que da paso a posibles abusos y a situaciones subjetivas. Si hay una pregunta planteada y respondida creo que es mejor intentar mejorar eso que ya existe entre todos y evitar la _clonación_, que indefectible generará situaciones desagradables.

Comment: La solución que proponéis se fija sólo en arreglar la pregunta. El problema es la respuesta aceptada de @A.Cedano Cambiando la pregunta ahora se queda sin responder correctamente como ya explicó también Luiggi. Hubiera sido mejor dejarla como **"Diferencias entre int e Integer"** y tendríamos dos publicaciones correctas. El que no vea la diferencia entre los dos asuntos no debería votar aunque pueda, porque no lo está comprendiendo. Por mi parte no tendréis mas problemas con esta pregunta. Yo abandono el sitio tras sufrir voto serial y que la moderación no responda a mis reportes. Adiós.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n La pregunta no ha sido cambiada. El usuario preguntaba por int[] e Integer[] y la pregunta sigue preguntando por int[] e Integer[]. Esto queda claro en que en el cuerpo de la pregunta el autor usa dos veces la palabra "vector". Al autor se le olvidaron los corchetes en el título. En cuanto a que la respuesta de Cedano está mal, incluso aunque tuvieses razón la solución no es duplicar una pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada cabe decir que lamento que estes pasando un mal rato. La idea este espacio es que lo pasemos bien ya este está espacio es para estar aquí por decisión y gusto propio.

En relación a la pregunta que ha sido marcada como duplicada, la persona a la que se atribuye la responsabilidad del marcado como duplicado, no se encuentra entre quienes votaron para marcarla como tal.

En la figura siguiente, tomada justo antes de que la pregunta fuera reabierta obsérvese que:

1. el recuaro amarillo en la parte infierior, en la cual se indica "**marcada** como duplicada por...".
2. se muestran que tiene 4 votos para reabrir.

[image]

Cabe hacer notar que en estos momentos la pregunta ya fue reabierta.

Comment: Gracias. Lo pensé dos veces antes de decir lo que dije y lo mantengo, aunque no haya intervenido en lo de marcarlo como duplicado, si te fijas en la pregunta del día 13, hay un debate entre Luiggi y yo por una parte y una especie de diálogo entre Luiggi y el autor de dicha pregunta-respuesta. Me he fijado que en muchas de mis respuestas él interviene en los comentarios tratando de desautorizar lo que contesto.

Comment: Una parte importante de la vida de comunidad es afrontar las diferencias que resultan significativas, y como parte de ello está el manifestar las informidadades, sin embargo, cuando un argumento tiene un error, debe este corregirse. En este caso en particular, el atribuir la responsabilidad del marcado como duplicado a la persona en cuestión está fuera de tema.

Comment: Bien. Corregiré eso. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pactemos desde ya que la pregunta más vieja tiene prioridad, y que si se dan respuestas mejores en la pregunta más nueva, la recomendación sea copiar esa respuesta en la pregunta más vieja.

A mí ya me ocurrió una vez y no tuve problema en copiar mi respuesta. Yo entiendo que acá estamos construyendo una base de conocimiento y cada pregunta debiera tener N buenas respuestas. Esto no es una competencia para ganar votos aprovechando preguntas sin responder que pueden ser duplicadas. Eso sí iría contra la idea de este sitio.

Comment: Desconozco si aquí ya se han fusionado preguntas, pero esto hace/haría que las respuestas y otros elementos de la pregunta duplicada se pasen/muevan a la pregunta canónica [What are merged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-are-merged-questions)

Comment: Sólo los Diamond Moderators pueden hacer eso. Los Diamond de SO Español son [Luiggi Mendoza](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza) y [Miquel Coll](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7242/miquel-coll)

Comment: Pues por favor que lo hagan :)

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. Si surge una nueva pregunta con mejor redactado, mejores respuestas y mejor SEO, creo que sería poco práctico marcarla como duplicada de una vieja con peor combinación de todo esto.

Comment: @fedorqui pero "mejor redactado" es una cuestión muy subjetiva. Acá estamos hablando de preguntas cuya redaccción sea muy similar y no se pueda declarar que una es superior a la otra, por lo que el criterio de fecha debiera primar, migrando claro las respuestas pertinentes

Comment: Mmm tu respuesta está formulada de una forma muy genérica: _Pactemos desde ya que la pregunta más vieja tiene prioridad, y que si se dan respuestas mejores en la pregunta más nueva, la recomendación sea copiar esa respuesta en la pregunta más vieja_. Y en eso es en lo que no estoy de acuerdo. En mi [larga] vida en [so] he visto multitud de ejemplos en los que la pregunta nueva tenía mejor redacción, explicación, etc., por lo que era mucho mejor marcar como duplicada la vieja.